# Is there a Python function to "spread" or group a (pandas) datetime dataframe per x hours?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

So I recently started working on Python for some data wrangling (normally use R but I want to learn Python aswell). And I'm looking at a dataframe very similar to this one:

[image]

[EDIT]
Here's some data without being in a picture format

```
    Datetime            X1      X3
1   07/07/2009 18:51    Group A Section 3
2   06/07/2009 18:44    Group C Unknown
3   07/07/2009 13:01    Group B Section 3
4   07/07/2009 02:22    Group B Section 2
5   06/07/2009 10:44    Group C Section 3
6   06/07/2009 21:07    Group A Section 3
7   07/07/2009 00:14    Group A Section 4
8   07/07/2009 11:50    Group C Unknown
9   06/07/2009 09:31    Group C Section 2
10  07/07/2009 11:24    Group B Unknown
11  07/07/2009 00:35    Group A Section 3
12  07/07/2009 15:26    Group A Section 1
13  06/07/2009 17:54    Group C Unknown
14  06/07/2009 07:44    Group A Section 2
15  06/07/2009 07:44    Group A Section 3
```

[/]

In this dataframe you see data entries per timestamp and I want to group and summarise them into 8-hour intervals (but it could be helpfull to make so flexible that I can change how many hours). This would result in the following desireable dataframe:

[image]

In R I would use the spread function of tidyr, but I'm not really sure how I could achieve the same with Python using only pandas and numpy (can't use others packages since it takes to long for authorization). Could anyone help me with this problem? Also in the complete dataframe I have many more X-variables, so tips with regard to that would be helpfull...

Comment: Please copy and paste the actual sample dataframe; do not use images.

Comment: I tried, but it gets turned into a picture automagically...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `get_dummies` and `pd.Grouper`

I should note that I am assuming your datetime column is formatted `mm/dd/yyyy` and not `dd/mm/yyyy`

```
# convert string date to datetime
df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Datetime']) # add dayfirst=True datetime is dd/mm/yyyy
# set Datetime column as index
df.set_index('Datetime', inplace=True)

# get dummies and groupby with pd.Grouper to set freq to 8 hours and then sum
df2 = pd.get_dummies(df).groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='8H')).sum()
# boolean indexing to remove rows with all zeros
df2[(df2.T != 0).any()]


                     X1_Group A  X1_Group B  X1_Group C  X3_Section 1  \
Datetime                                                                
2009-06-07 00:00:00           2           0           0             0   
2009-06-07 08:00:00           0           0           2             0   
2009-06-07 16:00:00           1           0           2             0   
2009-07-07 00:00:00           2           1           0             0   
2009-07-07 08:00:00           1           2           1             1   
2009-07-07 16:00:00           1           0           0             0   

                     X3_Section 2  X3_Section 3  X3_Section 4  X3_Unknown  
Datetime                                                                   
2009-06-07 00:00:00             1             1             0           0  
2009-06-07 08:00:00             1             1             0           0  
2009-06-07 16:00:00             0             1             0           2  
2009-07-07 00:00:00             1             1             1           0  
2009-07-07 08:00:00             0             1             0           2  
2009-07-07 16:00:00             0             1             0           0
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the time column is the correct data type. From your expected output, it looks like you want to make sure `dayfirst=True`.

```
>>> df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Datetime'], dayfirst=True)
```

Then we can use `pd.get_dummies` to convert all the different categorical values in the columns into separate columns that we can then sum over. Since it is temporal data you want to group by, we can use `pd.resample` with an 8 hour frequency instead of `pd.groupby` to make things slightly simpler. Finally sum over the columns to count the number of appearances in each group for the categorical values.

```
>>> df_8h = (pd.get_dummies(df, prefix='', prefix_sep='')
...            .resample('8H', on='Datetime')
...            .sum())
>>> df_8h
                         Group A      Group B      Group C   Section 1  \
Datetime                                                                 
2009-07-06 00:00:00            2            0            0           0   
2009-07-06 08:00:00            0            0            2           0   
2009-07-06 16:00:00            1            0            2           0   
2009-07-07 00:00:00            2            1            0           0   
2009-07-07 08:00:00            1            2            1           1   
2009-07-07 16:00:00            1            0            0           0   

                      Section 2   Section 3   Section 4   Unknown  
Datetime                                                           
2009-07-06 00:00:00           1           1           0         0  
2009-07-06 08:00:00           1           1           0         0  
2009-07-06 16:00:00           0           1           0         2  
2009-07-07 00:00:00           1           1           1         0  
2009-07-07 08:00:00           0           1           0         2  
2009-07-07 16:00:00           0           1           0         0
```